# Only getting varnish misses

Tags: performance, proxies

Would having the display errors setting turned on in the following admin page admin/config/development/logging cause Varnish to generate cache misses?

Comment: What happens when you turn it off? Does it fix the problem? That'll tell you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages are stored in the session (errors, warnings and info messages). If anything is in the session, a session cookie is set in the browser. If the session cookie is set in the browser, Varnish is normally bypassed.

Note, the name of the Drupal session cookie is `SESS` followed by a long hexadecimal string.